# Port forwarding through terminal

Tags: networking, server, firewall, minecraft

So, I have an Ubuntu server that I'd like to open a port for. I tried `ufw allow 25565`, but when I try and ping the IP address (with the port listening) it doesn't work. You can tell that it actually receives the ping, as the Minecraft server essentially has a seizure, but no information is sent back. I know that I'm supposed to port forward through the router, but I'm not sure I can do that through the terminal. Any solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First if possible through _router_ then do so, second: "but I'm not sure" or is it "but I'm sure"...?

Comment: I'm _not_ sure I can do it through the terminal, and, if I can, I don't know the command to do so.

Comment: Please do it in the router, that's the advice I have seen around here.

Comment: Well, yeah, obviously, but how would I go about that if there's no web interface?

Comment: let me drop a quick one and update it with more detail...

Comment: Please update your post to state these facts makes it easier to help you.